# Redshift table joins using Similar To

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, sql-like, regexp-like

I have this query that runs in Redshift:

```
Select A.* 
From TableA A 
join TableB B 
on A.Col like B.Pattern
```

Where the `Pattern` column in `TableB` looks like:

```
('%foo%', '%bar%', ...)
```

`TableB` has hundreds of pattern rules and is used in several locations to its easier and cleaner to maintain one table of string rules.

Is there a way to use `similar to` instead of `like` in the `join` condition in Redshift? I.e.
Select A.*
From TableA A
join TableB B
on A.Col similar to B.Pattern

When I try the above query, I get this error:

> Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me:

```
with cte1 AS (
    select 1 AS id, 'ABC'::varchar as col
    union
    select 2 AS id, 'BDE'::varchar AS col
), cte2 AS (
    select '%BC%'::varchar AS patt
)
select a.*
from cte1 a
inner join cte2 b
    ON a.col similar to b.patt
```

Comment: I tried converting your subqueries to temporary tables and the following causes the same error I originally received:
{
  Select *   
  Into #tmp1
  From (
      select 1 AS id, 'ABC'::varchar as col
      union
      select 2 AS id, 'BDE'::varchar AS col
   );  

  Select *   
  Into #tmp2
  From (
      select '%BC%'::varchar AS patt
   );     
   
  with cte1 AS (
   select * From #tmp1
  ), cte2 AS (
   Select * From #tmp2
  )
  select count(*)
  from cte1 a
  inner join cte2 b
  ON a.col similar to b.patt
}

Comment: Do you have any idea why when I alter your code to use temp tables instead of sub queries it doesnt work?